# Rent till death lease

Tags: rental-property, residential-lease, tenant

I have a lease that indicates my lease lasts till I die, with the terms that all bills (RE Tax, HOAs, utilities, all repairs, including a new roof if needed, all appliances,etc,etc,) ..  This was understood by both parties.  Can the house be sold without my permission ??

Comment: Usually there would be a separate section that identifies the owners rights to a sale. Even so, the lease could be transferred as part of the sale with the same terms with the new owner.

Comment: with terms that all bills *what*? Also, in what jurisdiction is the house? In most US states a lease is binding on a new owner if the property is sold.

Answer (score 3):

In most common law jurisdictions, yes. The new owner would be bound by the lease just as the old owner was.

Comment: Do you know if this is different in civil-law jurisdictions? (or are you just not prepared to make a positive statement about them)

Comment: Unfortunately, "this was understood by both parties" seems to indicate unwritten terms, which though still binding on the new owner may be hard to prove.